# Posets and tree diagrams

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The question asks me to draw a Hasse diagram for the given set of rules.
$$ (\{n\in \mathbb N: n\mid 100\ \lor\ n = 75 \}, {}\mid{} )  $$

My approach is to write down the set satisfying for $n\mid 100$, but I dont get what's with "or" $n =75.$

Could someone help me figure out what that means? is it set of all $n\mid100$ or $n\mid75$?

I'm new to discrete any solution is much appreciated.

Comment: The set $S$ on which you are putting the partial order relation "divisibility" is $S=\{1,2,4,5,10,20,25,50,100,75\}$. So $a$ is related to $b$ if $a$ divides $b$. For example, $10$ is related to $50$ but it is not related to $75$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the set of all $n$ such that one of the two conditions holds:

1) $n$ is a divisor of $100$

or

2) $n= 75$.

So, it's all the divisors of $100$ together with the single element $75$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{array}{rrcl}
& 1 & \times & 100 \\ = & 2 & \times & 50 \\ = & 4 & \times & 25 \\ = & 5 &  \times & 20 \\ = & 10 & \times &  10
\end{array}
The divisors of $100$ are $1,2,4,5,10,20,25, 50, 100.$

If divisors of $75$ were intended, it would have said $n\mid 75$ instead of $n=75.$ So the set you're looking at just contains divisors of  $100$ and that one additional number.

Your Hasse diagram would have $1$ at the bottom and prime numbers, $2$ and $5$, just above that. It should look like the Hasse diagram of divisors of $100$ except for one additional thing that corresponds to the relation $25\mid75.$

Comment: Thanks! I have a couple of doubts.
I will explain what i understood, correct me...

a.) I draw the tree diagram with 1 as the minimal element and 100 as the maximal element, and in between I have all the divisors of 100, 75 is added to this tree which is related to 25, as it divisible by it. 

b.) Where does 75 connect too? Is there a possibility of it becoming a maximal anti-chain?

Comment: @PrathikGurudatt : There is nothing that is divisible by $75$ in that set of numbers. It is a maximal element, as is $100,$ but neither $75$ nor $100$ is a maximum element, since in this case that would mean every number in the set is divisible by it. That's the difference between "maximum" and "maximal".